# why is my program crashing at the end

Tags: c++, while-loop, program-entry-point

here is my code:

```
int main(){

string inputcmd;

while (getline(cin, inputcmd)){
    cout << "TYPE A COMMAND" << endl;   
    cin >> inputcmd;
    //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    //cin.clear;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    if (inputcmd == "makenew"){

        cout << "MAKING NEW PROJECT";
        read_project(cin);
    }   
}

return 0;
}
```

why is my program always crashing at the end? it runs perfect until the very end, after i execute read_project() it then spits out a run time error and it crashes, why is this ?

Comment: Something in `read_project()` is corrupting memory.

Comment: on this website you should NEVER say that you get an error without saying what that error is.

Comment: the error is a run-time error as i previously noted. also i think i might have found the problem, @Barmar you were right, i fixed the function thanks

Comment: that sometimes happens if the interface for a method (in your case read_project(...)) is not a void but your method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your function "read_project", we don't know this function how to implement.